# How to use UIDocument in iOS for remote documents?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsurl, uidocumentinteraction

i want to display the pdf files as preview and display the PDF files in my app but pdfwhich i want to use are taking from the URL and display those pdf files in my document without using Web view but i want to display in  UIDocumentation only. but app is crashing if i used from URL? how to solve this problem,?

```
NSURL *URL =  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://golearning.blinkweb.com/uploads.00612104/00388749.pdf"];
if(URL)
{
    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];
    self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hey could you add what you've tried already and maybe some code to this question? That would be helpful for people trying to answer your question.

Comment: NSURL *URL =  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://golearning.blinkweb.com/uploads.00612104/00388749.pdf"];
    if(URL)
    {
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];
        self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
        [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    }   but app crashng giving log asTerminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme http.  Only the file scheme is supported.'

Comment: Hey Jonathan just curious why you rolled back the edited version? It looked like a bit of an improvement. Also @chaithraVeeresh if you could add the code to the question that would be great.

Comment: i added code what i've used in app . if i used that pdf file from bundlee its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here really lies in Chaithra's comment:

`UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme http.  Only the file scheme is supported`

To solve this problem you need to download the PDF file, obtain a local URL for it and can then pass it onto the `UIDocumentInteractionController`.  Using AFNetworking as a baseline the following worked for me:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSProgress *progress = nil;
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
  NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                                     inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                            appropriateForURL:nil
                                                                       create:NO error:nil];
  return [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
  [self displayDocument:filePath];
}];


[downloadTask resume];
```

My `displayDocument:` method looks like this:

```
- (void)displayDocument:(NSURL*)document {
  UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:document];
  documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
  [documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
```

And the following delegate method:

```
- (UIViewController*)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
  return self;
}
```

Without using `AFNetworking` the code would be broadly similar as most of the classes used in the above sample are standard anyway.  I happen to be using AFNetworking in this instance to simplify some of the setup and automatically using the categories it provides around `UIProgress` to update a progress bar for me.